# Can't get a canvas element to rotate properly

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm trying to animate a rotating repeat icon on a canvas but it's not spinning around the center of the image. I'm not sure what to do to make it spin properly.

```
setInterval(draw, 30);
    var degrees = 0.0;

    function draw() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');

        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
            degrees += 0.10;

            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(8,8);
            ctx.rotate(degrees);

            // Draw half open circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.arc(8, 8, 6, 0, 1.75 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();

            // Draw arrowhead
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.moveTo(13, 1);
            ctx.lineTo(9, 5);
            ctx.lineTo(13, 5);
            ctx.lineTo(13, 1);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xTFkU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were rotating the canvas and translating, but drawing then performing your drawing functions as if the canvas wasn't translated.

Basically what you need to do is translate the canvas to half of the width and height of the image you're drawing. This will make 0,0 the center of the image. Then you subtract the offset from all of your coordinates.

What I did was add an offset value that is your width and height divided by 2. I then translated the canvas by that offset, and subtracted that offset from all of the coordinates.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/xTFkU/2/)**

```
(function() {

    setInterval(draw, 30);
    var degrees = 0.0;
    var offset = 8;
    function draw() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');

        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
            degrees += 0.10;

            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(offset, offset);
            ctx.rotate(degrees);

            // Draw half open circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.arc(8-offset , 8-offset, 6, 0, 1.75 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();

            // Draw arrowhead
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.moveTo(13-offset , 1-offset);
            ctx.lineTo(9-offset , 5-offset);
            ctx.lineTo(13-offset , 5-offset);
            ctx.lineTo(13-offset , 1-offset);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
})();​
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So from what I understand is that you don't actually rotate the canvas with it's contents. Instead you're changing the rotation of the starting point, so every element you draw has to be adjusted for that?

Comment: yeah thats exactly it. Im terrible at explaining it heres a code example I did a while back that does a better job of explaining it http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/v86rC/ theres a few ways to do it, basically it all comes down to where you translate, from there you know the offsets you need.

Answer (score 0):

With `ctx.translate(8,8);` you moved the coordinate origin into the center of your canvas, then rotated. You now will need to paint a circle around the center (`0/0`), not around the point (`8/8`): http://jsfiddle.net/xTFkU/4/. Alternatively, you can move the rotated coordinate system back by `ctx.translate(-8,-8);`: http://jsfiddle.net/xTFkU/5/